# In if test the list contains only one specific string or multiple same specific string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list file as

```
mike
jack
jack
mike
```

sometimes is (no mike)

```
jack
jack
```

I would like to test whether this file only contains one `mike` or multiple `mike`'s like following

```
if [list **only** contains one `mike` or multiple `mike`'s]
then
do something
else
echo jack(other's name) is using it
done
```

Comment: You want it be in `bash` or okay with others like `awk` ?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I do not understand what do you mean. I am new to shell scripting. I am using `bash`.

Comment: There are many dedicated tools to iterate through the file and perform some actions say, awk, sed or grep. You can always implement these solutions in native bash but will take more number of lines to implement the same

Comment: I try to reword the task: Is there any _unwanted_ entry in the file? _Unwanted_ is anything except `mike`.

Comment: @81256 Is my "rephrasing" OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ "$(sort inputfile | uniq)" = mike ]
```

sort the input, then remove all identical lines. You need to sort the input for `uniq` because it works only for consecutive identical lines.

Short form:

```
[ "$(sort --unique inputfile)" = mike ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution in `bash`**

You can use a `while` loop with `read` to read through the lines as

```
while read line; 
do  
   [ $line == "mike" ] && ((count=$count+1)) 
done < inputFile
```

The `$count` will contain the count of `mike` in the file.

```
$ echo $count
2
```

---

**Solution in `awk`**

```
$ awk '/mike/{count++}; END{print count}' input
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find_mike () { 
    mike_count=$(grep -c 'mike');
    if (( mike_count == 1 )); then
        printf 'I found only one mike.'
    elif (( mike_count > 1 )); then
        printf 'I found %d mikes.' "$mike_count"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "I have no idea where is mike";
    fi
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
$ find_mike < input_file.txt
I found 2 mikes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -xvq mike inputfile
```

- -x: match the whole line
- -v: invert the match
- -q: do not print anything; exit at first match

This command exits with 0 as soon as it finds something that is not `mike`. If the file is empty or contains only (any number of) `mike` lines, it exits with 1.

`grep` is very, very fast. And it stops as soon as possible parsing the input file.

You might want to invert the exit value by prefixing the command with an exclamation mark.